# Form To Upload Multiple Images & Data To MySQL DB Via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

We are developing an application for internal use only to upload 2 images and some text boxes to a MySQL database via a form and PHP Script.

We can get a simple form to work where only text boxes are submitted with no image fields, and we can get a form with just image fields to work and upload images to the mySQL database as BLOB, but when combining the 2 we can only get it to upload the images, and not the text boxes.

Please find below the code for our php upload script, when our form is submitted this uploads to the database the 2 image fields as BLOB, but not the other text fields, any help to point out where we have gone wrong is greatly appreciated:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","outofhours");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

$sitename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sitename']);
$siteaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['siteaddress']);
$sitepostcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sitepostcode']);
$eqmake = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqmake']);
$eqmodel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqmodel']);
$eqdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqdesc']);
$eqserial = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqserial']);
$eqassetno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqassetno']);
$eqconttype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqconttype']);
$brewery = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['brewery']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);
$onsitetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['onsitetime']);
$offsitetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['offsitetime']);
$custprintname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['custprintname']);
$custposition = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['custposition']);
$engname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['engname']);

// check if a file was submitted
if(!isset($_FILES['engsig1']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
    $msg= upload();  //this will upload your image
    echo $msg;  //Message showing success or failure.
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
    }
}



// the upload function

function upload() {
    include "file_constants.php";
    $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

    //check associated error code
        if($_FILES['engsig1']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['engsig1']['tmp_name'])) {    

            //checks size of uploaded image on server side
            if( $_FILES['engsig1']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

               //checks whether uploaded file is of image type
                 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['engsig1']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {    
                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData1 =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['engsig1']['tmp_name']));
                    $imgData2 =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['custsig1']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db ($db) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO oohours (sitename, siteaddress, sitepostcode, eqmake, eqmodel, eqdesc, eqserial, eqassetno, eqconttype, brewery, date, onsitetime, offsitetime, custprintname, custsig1, custposition, engname, engsig1)
                    VALUES
                    ('$sitename', '$siteaddress', '$sitepostcode', '$eqmake', '$eqmodel', '$eqdesc', '$eqserial', '$eqassetno', '$eqconttype', '$brewery', '$date', '$onsitetime', '$offsitetime', '$custprintname', '{$imgData1}', '$custposition', '$engname', '{$imgData2}')";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database with id ='. mysql_insert_id().' </p>';
                }
                else
                    $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";
            }
             else {
                // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                <div>File '.$_FILES['engsig1']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['engsig1']['size'].
                ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
        }
        else
            $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else {
        $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['engsig1']['error']);
    }
    return $msg;
}

// Function to return error message based on error code

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are using `MYSQL` and `MYSQLI` functions through each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error lies probably in the fact you are using mysql and mysqli functions through each other. This doesnt work. Either you go with mysqli or you got with mysql .. i would go for mysqli.

I mean, check for yourself. You sanitize them with mysqli, but within the upload function to connect to the database, you use a mysql function.

```
                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db ($db) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO oohours (sitename, siteaddress, sitepostcode, eqmake, eqmodel, eqdesc, eqserial, eqassetno, eqconttype, brewery, date, onsitetime, offsitetime, custprintname, custsig1, custposition, engname, engsig1)
                    VALUES
                    ('$sitename', '$siteaddress', '$sitepostcode', '$eqmake', '$eqmodel', '$eqdesc', '$eqserial', '$eqassetno', '$eqconttype', '$brewery', '$date', '$onsitetime', '$offsitetime', '$custprintname', '{$imgData1}', '$custposition', '$engname', '{$imgData2}')";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database with id ='. mysql_insert_id().' </p>';
```

is mysql function, while you use for the rest mysqli

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","outofhours");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

$sitename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sitename']);
$siteaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['siteaddress']);
$sitepostcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sitepostcode']);
$eqmake = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqmake']);
$eqmodel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqmodel']);
$eqdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqdesc']);
$eqserial = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqserial']);
$eqassetno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqassetno']);
$eqconttype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['eqconttype']);
$brewery = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['brewery']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);
$onsitetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['onsitetime']);
$offsitetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['offsitetime']);
$custprintname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['custprintname']);
$custposition = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['custposition']);
$engname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['engname']);
```

So at that point, you have established the connection with a mysql in the function, but your text is in mysqli sanitized, so it has no clue what to do with it. Simple said as a bove, you chose one or the other ;)

Comment: Hello, We have changes it to MySQL but it still wont work:
http://notepad.cc/hoislaso56
Have we missed something out?
Thanks

Comment: echo out the $sql and see what it returns, and throw that through php my admin, see if that works? Somewhere something is not set i guess. I cant see right now the problem, after walking through it.

Comment: We have echo'd it out, and all the values are showing as blank apart from the image ones.

Comment: okay so you know at least where it goes wrong, i asume. Are they all placed in the correct form? (not 2 seperate forms)? Cause you only check if the image isset, not the rest of your data.

Comment: Hello,
After further testing (placing echo $sitename in to different parts of the scripts) we have found that the values are stored, but then as soon as the function starts, the value no longer displays, so the error is within that function.

Comment: When we removed the function it works. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You re welcome. I was about to tell you to define them within the function then, or use a global statement. See for more information here. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php